# How to change column span to row span by CSS FLEX for RWD

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to use same HTML structure to display a Table that made of FLEX on the desktop and mobile, but I have no idea to change column span to row span, I know `position: absolute` it's not a good idea for maintaining

[image]

---

[codepen](https://codepen.io/lichunbin814/pen/RyQzbr)

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}

.block {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.block1 {
    background-color: cadetblue;
}

.block2 {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.block3 {
    background-color: beige;
}

.col-span {
    height: 100%;
}

/* row span */

.row-span-sample {
   position: relative;
}

.row-span {
    width: 200%;
    position: absolute;
    left: -100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>column span on Desktop</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="block block1 col-span">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="block block2">2</div>
    <div class="block block3">3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>row span on mobile</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row row-span-sample">
    <div class="block block1">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-span-sample">

    <div class="block block2">2</div>
    <div class="block block3 row-span">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can I change it without `position: absolute`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}

.block {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.block1 {
    background-color: cadetblue;
}

.block2 {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.block3 {
    background-color: beige;
}

.col-span {
    height: 100%;
}

/* row span */

.row-span-sample {
   position: relative;
}

.row-span {
    width: 200%;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    left: -100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>column span on Desktop</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="block block1 col-span">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="block block2">2</div>
    <div class="block block3">3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>row span on mobile</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row row-span-sample">
    <div class="block block1">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-span-sample">

    <div class="block block2">2</div>
    <div class="block block3 row-span">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What have I done? Just change `absolute` value from `position` property, and change it to `relative`.

And the set `left` property to `0`.

And why this works? Because, if you have a position defined (`relative` or `absolute`) then you can set the position (because we are get used to set them only when `absolute` positions are present).

Also, you can set it without `left: 0;` statment. Relative positions are better than absolute ones, but you need to know how them works.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very simple solution using CSS Grid Layout and a media query.

No absolute positioning.

No nested containers.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 200px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "one two"
    "one three";
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-areas:
      "one two"
      "three three";
  }
}

.block1 { grid-area: one; background-color: cadetblue; }
.block2 { grid-area: two; background-color: cornflowerblue; }
.block3 { grid-area: three; background-color: beige; }

.block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="block block1">1</div>
    <div class="block block2">2</div>
    <div class="block block3">3</div>
</div>
```

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KRoRBK?editors=1100)

Comment: I like this answer,  and I will try on old IOS version(10.2, 10.3.2) from my coworkers because Grid Layout can't work on their phone at last time

Comment: so sad, it can't run on IOS 10.2, do you have any suggestion to fix it?